# why SPFieldUserValue is null

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

When I am trying to iterate `SPFieldUserValueCollection` I am not getting `SPFieldUserValue` value. But it is going to if condition and saying value is null.

If convert field to MultipleAllowed= No and use `SPFieldUserValue` that I can get value for single user ( not using `SPFieldUserValueCollection`)

```
SPFieldUserValueCollection fieldValues = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)lstItem["SPE Primary Contact"];

  foreach (SPFieldUserValue fieldValue in fieldValues)
  {
    if (fieldValue != null)
    {

    }
  }
```